# How to show that the infinite sum of $(-1)^x$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm working through some introductory taylor series problems and I've come across something like this a number of times.

$\sum (-1)^x$

I know that this diverges, but I cannot think of how to prove it to myself.

When I think about it, it seems to just constantly be adding a negative one and a positive one which means its constantly going back and forth between either -1 and 0 or between 0 and 1 depending on the starting location of k

Would it be possible to use a comparison or limit comparison test and compare it to a trig function? Or could I use a test for divergence and maybe the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Remember an infinite sum is the limit of its partial sums

Comment: I found [this chart](https://bccalculus.wikispaces.com/file/view/flow_chart.JPG/147971387/flow_chart.JPG) indispensable during my studies of sequences and series!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s really quite simple: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ (-1)^n\right]$ does not approach $0$; hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[ (-1)^n\right]$ diverges.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, so a simple test for divergence would work. You don't even necessarily need to continue with it because it just doesnt approach zero. Thanks for that clarification

Answer (score 1):

Additional approach: an infinite series is defined as the limit of partial sums. If you define $$S_n=\sum_{x=1}^{n}\left[(-1)^x\right]$$ then the sequence $\{S_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is called a toggling sequence. If you plot these values on a graph, you will see that the sequence of partial sums does not agree on a specific asymptote, hence $S_\infty$ is not defined.